# JQuery BlockUI on "normal" forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, blockui, jquery-blockui

I have searched hi and low, but can't find an answer without a lot of work. I have a site that has lots of intensive forms. I am trying to write a global function that will gray out or block the UI when any form is submitted on the site. They do not all have a class, an id, etc. Some submit via a regular submit button, some already have javascript submit buttons, etc.

Is there a simple way to say when any form gets submitted it will gray out the site system wide?

Comment: What's the point of graying out the page, to keep the user from acting until the form is done processing?  Your motivation will help us find an answer.

Comment: Yes, to keep them from interacting or thinking that nothing is going on - both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use an [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) to get all `<form>` elements, then hook a handler up to the [`submit` event](http://api.jquery.com/submit/), like this:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
  $(this).block(/* options here if needed */);
});
```

Comment: I'll try this - I thought it would be something simple, but I didn't realize there was a element selector - I'm new to jQuery and looked all over for that, just couldn't find it. I'll let you know in a bit